# How can you update many rows in database with only 1 single data in vb 2010?

Tags: insert-update

is it possible with me.tableadaptermanager.updateAll(me.dataset)?
i have 1 textbox.. i want that its value will be update multiple rows in the same table..

for example.. i'll filter the tbTransaction table with EmpName, datebegin, dateend..
so now the table is filtered with EmpName, datebegin, and dateend..
for example, for the filtered data, they all have status field.. they are not the same because they have different dates.. so i want my value in textbox.. only single value from my vb 2010 textbox to update the status field with the same data one i clicked submit button..

is that possible?

Comment: in short i want to update them all not one by one but only once..

Comment: There are two ways of doing this: 1) looping through your dataset, update the desired rows, and use the DataAdapter to apply those changes back to the database.  or 2) design a SQL UPDATE command and use the Command object to run it against your DB. Have you tried either, or do you have a preference?

Comment: could you give me some example? im a newbie in programming..